# Conflict on script ajax with others

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My script is causing conflict with others, when I use the line `.noConflict ();` it works fine, but another script stops working. If I remove the line `.noConflict ();` the script stops working and another script returns to normal. What can it be?
I use https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js after body is open.

```
$(function() {
    $("#contact .button").click(function() {
        var name = $("#form_name").val();
        var email = $("#form_email").val();
        var text = $("#msg_text").val();
        var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&text=' + text;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "email_demo.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(){
                $('#success').fadeIn(1000);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

I try this but not work

```
            a$.noConflict();
            a$(function() {
                a$("#contact .button").click(function() {
                    var name = $("#form_name").val();
                    var email = $("#form_email").val();
                    var text = $("#msg_text").val();
                    var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&text=' + text;

                    a$.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "email_demo.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        success: function(){
                            a$('#success').fadeIn(1000);
                        }
                    });

                    return false;
                });
            });
```

my form:

```
<form name="solicitarDemo" method="post" class="" id="contact">  
 <section id="left">
   <label for="form_name">Name</label>
     <input name="form_name" id="form_name" type="text" >

   <label for="form_email">Email</label>
     <input name="form_email" id="form_email" type="email" >
 </section>

 <section id="right">
   <label for="form_msg">Message</label>
     <textarea name="form_msg" id="form_msg"></textarea>
   <input id="submit" class="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
 </section>

</form>

<div id="success" style="width:60%; display: none;">
Solicitação enviada, aguarde nosso contato em breve.
</div>
```

scripts:

```
<body>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <!--  conflict with this script-->
        <script src="sliderPro/js/jquery.sliderPro.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm guessing that jquery.sliderPro.min.js includes jQuery. If so you have two versions of jQuery that are conflicting.

Comment: @DanielTate no conflict before add my form. the two .js worked together before. I tried removing one of them now, but any of them that I try to remove does not work well on the slider.

Comment: Check the minified slider pro source to see what version of jQuery it contains if any. If it doesn't contain jQuery you can probably rule this out as the issue. Make sure you have matching versions try including the full jquery library instead of the slim version to see if that helps.

Are you including ANY other scripts?

Comment: @DanielTate you are a genius, I try https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js and work all scripts. thanks